# Percolate in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch-percolate

What we usually do is index documents and get them back by querying. What the percolator allows to do in a nutshell is index queries and percolate documents against the indexed queries to know which queries they match. It's also called reversed search.

Is it possible to percolate in PostgreSQL?

[Percolate Query in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html)

Comment: If your queries are *text search queries* you can probably store a collection of [`tsquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY) and `JOIN on to_tsvector(document) @@ query`.

Comment: @joanolo I think, although a useful functionality with which tsqueries can provide you with part of ES text search functionality, they are not a replacement for percolation search, which is more broad concept - matching a document/record against a search/query.